# Workflow in SharePoint

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a workflow for Birthday.
I used custom list for this with the columns

1. DOB
2. Name
3. Age

**Requirement** :

I want to send the Birthday mail when user has his birthday.once the mail wishing mail is send workflow will stop/pause till the next birthday

I want to achive looping in sp 2010.

I manage to send mail based on the date of birth But unable to find way for looping

I don't want to use any code. All i used is designer and site column.

Comment: Better, you can use sharepoint calendar list. And set up the task https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/23664-rotating-birthday-list-in-sharepoint

Comment: Having multiple workflows instances running for one year each at the time is a bad idea. How many employees do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can create list workflow for the same where you can make that workflow pause for one day(loop). Below is the example.[image]

Comment: If this answer has resolved your problem, then please accept and upvote the same.